# Trying to put array of anything into method parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, type-conversion, ienumerable

I have a little problem: I created this method

```
private static Dictionary<object, int> StuffToDictionary(IEnumerable<object> input) 
{ 
    var dict = new Dictionary<object, int>();

    foreach (var word in input)
    {
        try
        {
            dict.Add(word, 1);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            dict[word]++;
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```

and variable calling this method //not working yet ;)

```
var input = args[0];
Console.WriteLine("Character frequencies:\n" + StuffToDictionary(input));
```

How should I change my code (type of the input parameter, declaration of variable or whatever) so I can put there at least array of chars or ints not only object types variables array

I tried to convert input to almost everything but still did not found solution

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the algorithm is incoherent (the add with the ++ in the catch smell bad). What is args[0]? What do you try to do with the method?

Comment: yeah i removed try catch as ZorgoZ suggested it was kinda weird ;) but generic method was solution i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private static Dictionary<T, int> StuffToDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) 
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<T, int>();

  foreach (var key in input)
  {
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) 
    {
        dict[key]++;
    }
    else
    {
        dict[key]=1;
    }
  }

  return dict;
}
```

However, you won't be able to use it in `WriteLine` and stuff as it has no meaningful `ToString` override. If you need such things, you better create a specialized `StuffDictionary` class instead of just a method.

On the other hand you should not use exceptions for such checks, although it works, it is a much expensive alternative and an antipattern if there is any direct approach.

Comment: @MatusBabinsky You are welcome. If this is what you were looking for, feel free to accept it.